# How do I get the Google user ID from an email address?

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I want to display the GMail avatar of the user in my app. I can easily get the image URL, using the Google People API. But this API expects a user ID.

Which other Google API can I use to pass in an email address, and get back the user ID?

Answer (score 1):

The Google people api is technically hooked up to Google Contacts. So if you authenticate your user and they have added themselves with a picture you will see it that way.

The Google+ api will work the same way you authenticate the user and if they have added a picture you will be able to see it.

> Which other Google API can I use to pass in an email address, and get back the user ID?

NONE.  There is no way Google or any other company is going to give you an api that is going to let you search on peoples email addresses and return a picture or any information about said person you may want to consult [GDRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)

Email address is private user information and is only accessible by being authenticated.